# how can i insert the dummy records in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table `TxnEnrollment` having columns `FamilyID,Ename,address,age` and so on like

```
FamilyID          EName          Address                  age
02748471070198329 TILOK CHAND    H.No.- D-248, SHAKUR     24
```

And I have also a second table having column `FamilyId ,MemberID MemberName age` like

```
FamilyID           MemberID  MemberName   Gender     Age RelationCode   
02748471070198329  1         TILOK CHAND   1         65 
02748471070198329  2         SHANTI        2         60   2         
02748471070198329  3         DUMMY RECORD  1         99         
02748471070198329  4         INSERT        1         99   17            
02748471070198329  5         PUT DETAILS   1         99
```

Now my question is that suppose in a family there is 5 member whose familyID should be `same` but the memberID should be `different` like above table  and if in a family there is only three member then how can I insert two more dummy record like 'insert' and 'dummy records'.

Comment: Wow I am so confused on what you are trying to ask here, but I assume you want MemberID as a primary auto increment.

Comment: is there any link between the first and second tables?  FamilyID just seems to be a random number....

Comment: yes there is link between familyID in the both table

Comment: Pls provide your existing  Query, also look on relationship `one to many`  or `many to many`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what this second table has to do with your question. I just focused on the problem, that you want to have for every familyId all memberIds from 1 to 5. If one of them doesn't exist, you want to insert the row, have I understood that right? If yes, here's an example of how to do it.

```
create table foo (id int, another_id int, some_col varchar(20));
insert into foo (id, another_id, some_col) values 
(111,1, 'asdf'), 
(111,3, 'asdf'), 
(111,4, 'asdf'), 
(222,2, 'asdf'), 
(222,3, 'asdf'), 
(222,5, 'asdf');

create table dummy (dummies int);
insert into dummy values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);


insert into foo (id, another_id, some_col)
select 
sq.id, sq.dummies, "I'm a dummy"
from
foo f
right join 
(
select distinct
id, dummies
from
foo 
, dummy 
) sq on f.id = sq.id and f.another_id = sq.dummies
where f.another_id is null;
```

> select * from foo order by id, another_id;

Output:

```
ID  ANOTHER_ID  SOME_COL
111     1   asdf
111     2   I'm a dummy
111     3   asdf
111     4   asdf
111     5   I'm a dummy
222     1   I'm a dummy
222     2   asdf
222     3   asdf
222     4   I'm a dummy
222     5   asdf
```